# magento category under each instead of next?

Tags: php, magento

How to let magento category under each instead of next and then after like 4 under move to to a column next to it?

Default order:

APPLES - BANANAS - CITRON - DILEMMA - EGYPT - FARAO

What i want:

APPLES               -   EGYPT

BANANAS       -  FARAO

CITRON - ETC..

DILEMMA - ETC..

Code can be found at  subcategory_listing.phtml

Please let me know how to change that code?

Comment: Is there people here?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the modulus operator to determine all odd, or even categories in your loop. For example:

```
$i = 0;
foreach($categories as $category):
    $i++;
    echo $category->getName() . " ";
    if($i % 2):
        echo "<br/>";
    endif;


endforeach;
```

This example outputs two categories on the same row. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find subcategory_listing.phtml

Anyway, something like this should make the trick:

```
$rowNum = 4;
$rows = array_fill(0, $rowNum, '');
$i = 0;
foreach($categories as $category) {
    $rows[$i % $rowNum] .= " [$category] ";
    $i++;
}
echo implode('<br />', $rows);
```